# Out of memory when compiling Magento 2 - increasing memory doesn't work

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, setup-di-compile, memory

When compiling Magento 2, I'm getting the error:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 294125568) (tried to allocate 32
>   bytes) in /vendor/zendframework/zend-code/src/Scanner/FileScanner.php
>   on line 36

I've read a ton of answers to this question, and everyone suggests using `-dmemory_limit` to increase memory while compiling. I've tried 756M, 4G, 5G, 8G, 16G, etc and it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: check to the php info for your memory_limit value

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the `memory_limit` in **php.ini**

In Your `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` or find your loaded ini file by creating info.php file and look for **Loaded Configuration File**.

Find `memory_limit` in php.ini file and increase memory limit to

> memory_limit = 2G